# build layout at runtime android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

i have a complex xml layout which has list views..a row in the list view contains several text fields which are spaced evenly. i am using textview to store the text and then finally add all the items to the row...its working perfectly fine.
but now i have case where in i am not sure, how many text fields i might get from a webservice. therefore i need to create the textview dynamically on run time, populate them and then insert into the list..
is there anyway to declare,add and populate new textview fields on runtime?
or is there is anyway to implement the spacing between the two fields?

result of first call

```
__________________________
|_____|_____|_____|______|
```

result of second call

```
________________________________
|_____|_____|_____|______|______|
```

I tried implementing the solution that was provided below (Kenny), but for some reason I am unable to add views into the list.. below is my code

```
public class HeaderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Header> {
final Header[] listSymbols;
private TextView textView;
private LinearLayout row;

public HeaderAdapter(Context context, int symResourceID,
        Header[] objects) {
    super(context, symResourceID, objects);
    listSymbols = objects;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_view, parent, false);
    Header headerRec = listSymbols[position];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < listSymbols.length;i++){
        textView = new TextView(getContext());
        textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  //Width of the view
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));//Height of the view
        textView.setId(i);
            row.add??

        }
}
```

The main activity that calls this

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);

    headerList.add(new Header("Symbol","Quantity","Price","Price Yesterday","52 Week High","52 Week Low","Change","Days Gain","Days Gain %","Returns"));

            Header[] tmpHeaderList = headerList.toArray(new Header[headerList.size()]);

            ArrayAdapter<Header> headerAdapter = new HeaderAdapter(this,R.layout.twoway_header_view,tmpHeaderList);
            headerListView.setAdapter(headerAdapter);
```

xml layout file..the main file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollbars="none"
        android:id="@+id/headerHv">

        <ListView android:id="@+id/header_listView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white" android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true" android:scrollbars="none" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

the file in which the template for the row is defined

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/headerList" android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"
        android:typeface="sans" android:textStyle="normal"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the way i dynamically generate custom buttons from a list, you could do the same thing with textViews:

```
//Setup Buttons
    layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutBars);
    int count = lBars.size();
    for(int i = 0; i< count;i++){
        final Bar b = lBars.get(i);
        BarButton button = new BarButton(DDTBars.this, R.drawable.barsmall , b.getName().toUpperCase());
        button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        button.setId(i);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Run activity passing name of the bar to retrieve data
                Intent i = new Intent(DDTBars.this, DDTBar.class);
                i.putExtra("name", b.getName());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        layout.addView(button);         
    }
```

So you could try:

```
    //Setup TextViews
    layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
    int count = myTextList.size();
    for(int i = 0; i< count;i++){
        TextView txtView = new TextView(this);
        txtView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  //Width of the view
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));//Height of the view
        txtView.setId(i);
        layout.addView(txtView);            
    }
```

Comment: @Kenny...thanks...but here you use BarButton, is there anything like that for textview?

Comment: BarButton is a custom button i made, all buttons extend the View class, textViews also extend the view class. so you can do exactly the same but add a textView rather than a button.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to show you, please mark the question as answered to remove it from the unanswered list.

Comment: @Kenny..thank you for the solution..but i have this adapter that is helps me populate the row..and i am not able to add the view in the row..could you kindly help me with this .. i have added my code in the question

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in code. Declare TextView 's in a loop and use RelativeLayout to position them wrt each other.